# date part equality in LinqTo Entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, datetime, linq-to-entities

From the MSDN site

> The Date property, which returns a DateTime value that represents a date **without its time component**

Well this method

```
public List<int> GetSymbolIdsFromProjectionsForDate(DateTime testDate)
{
    var date = testDate.Date;
    var db = _projContext;
    List<int> symbList;
    using (db)
    {
         symbList =
       db.CommodityProjections.Where(e => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.ProjectionDate) == date)
                              .Select(e => e.CommoditySymbolId)
                              .ToList();
    }
    return symbList;
}
```

The list count is always zero. So while debugging, I see that the date variable is actually NOT just the date component of a datetime as it shows
Date = {11/14/2015 12:00:00 AM}

WTF So how does one compare dates using SQL Server. (I just migrated from MySql, where this was easier IMHO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` on both dates.

```
.Where(e => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.ProjectionDate) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(testDate)
```